# Angular2 rc5 #myForm="ngForm" erroring

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("<div class="col-xs-6" id="search-bar-container">
<form [ERROR ->]#myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="doSearch()">
```

I have, at the top of the corresponding component:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

I haven't found anything by Googling (as far as I can tell, anyway - there seems to be plenty of change between RCs on this one).

Can anyone (no doubt ultra-simply) point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you also add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` to `imports: []` of `@NgModule()`?

Comment: Show us your `@NgModule()`.

Comment: I hadn't - thank you. Weirdly though, having done so, I get a warning about it not being able to find @angular/forms. It all seems to work, though ...

Comment: Missing module error squashed - not sure why it occurred in the first place, but reinstalling @angular/forms fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Update to the latest version of Angular 2 to fix the problem.

I'm guessing that you're mixing up the Angular 2 versions. The FormsModule that you reference, will only work in the latest version of Angular 2 (maybe RC.5 too, not sure though). And as I'm understanding from your question, you're still using an older version.

To get the Forms working, it is best to update your application to the latest version of Angular 2. At least RC.6 (which is the latest when I'm writing this).
If you haven't used any `NgModule` classes in your application, you will have to update to use the `FormsModule`.

Then you'll have to introduce `NgModule` classes in your project (have a look at the [Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#root-component)). In this `NgModule` you'll have to add `FormsModule` to the `imports`. That way, all Components referenced in the `NgModule` will be able to use the components from the FormsModule. And in the `FormsModule`, the logic to use the `ngForm` and `ngModel` (which you'll probably need too)

But all this, is also explained on the [Angular website about using forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html). In more detail than I can add in this post.